# Triggering the @schedule based on the completion of another @schedule method in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, methods, synchronization

I have two methods annotated with @scheduled in a spring boot application. I want one of the method to wait for 10 minutes after first @scheduled method finishes execution.

Currently I am setting 15 minutes for first job and 30 minutes for second job. Some times first job executes for long and the sync is breaking.

Want to time the second @scheduled method based on another @scheduled methods execution.

Comment: I have an idea of storing a value after the first @scheduled method executes. The second scheduled can check that variable to decide whether to execute or not.

Answer (score 1):

If your second method is that dependent on the first one then it should probably just be part of the first one and not have its own @Scheduled annotation.

But yes your idea could work, you would need a static long (lets call it dateFlag) that you set to new Date().getTime() after the first method finishes. Then the second method will have an if statement at the beginning, something like 
if (new Date().getTime - dateFlag > 600000) { ... }

600000 being 10 minutes in milliseconds, if you need some other time then this tool is handy https://www.timecalculator.net/minutes-to-milliseconds